# getting initramfs shell in initramfs on cm4

Tags: pi-4

I'm using a CM4 (with the console being a serial console).   Everything is working EXCEPT getting control of the console in initramfs -- I can't echo (much less get a shell).

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 server.

I'm booting with "verbose debug" (not quiet).   Looking at the init script, the printf (log_msg) never come out).

When I add echos or printfs are certain points in my initramfs init script, it just stops there.

I really want to do something like break=init -- it works fine on intel platforms (I tried ubuntu 21.04 with vbox) -- but I don't know why rpi isn't working.

I commented out run-init -- and this shows on the console:

```
[    6.841542] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.985488] printk: systemd-udevd: 27 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
[    7.042109] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
[    7.049889] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: sh Not tainted 5.4.0-1068-raspi #78-Ubuntu
[    7.056860] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0 (DT)
[    7.063389] Call trace:
[    7.065869]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x198
[    7.069577]  show_stack+0x28/0x38
[    7.072933]  dump_stack+0xd8/0x134
[    7.076378]  panic+0x160/0x35c
[    7.079469]  complete_and_exit+0x0/0x38
[    7.083353]  do_group_exit+0x4c/0xa8
[    7.086973]  __wake_up_parent+0x0/0x48
[    7.090769]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x84/0x230
[    7.095622]  el0_svc_handler+0x38/0xa0
[    7.099419]  el0_svc+0x10/0x140
[    7.102602] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[    7.106578] Kernel Offset: 0x28347d800000 from 0xffff800010000000
[    7.112753] PHYS_OFFSET: 0xffffacd080000000
[    7.116990] CPU features: 0x10002,20806000
[    7.121139] Memory Limit: none
[    7.124236] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing:
```

And the init script has:

```
shellcheck disable=SC2086,SC2094
exec run-init ${drop_caps} "${rootmnt}" "${init}" "$@" <"${rootmnt}/dev/console" >"${rootmnt}/dev/console" 2>&1
echo "Something went badly wrong in the initramfs."
panic "Please file a bug on initramfs-tools."
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.
I have one console (the default seems to have two consoles -- the serial and across hdmi -- I'm only using the serial).

I needed to add this to init in initramfs:

exec >/dev/console
exec 2>/dev/console